# Understanding order of operation of cgroup configuration files in /etc/systemd/system/*

Tags: rhel, cgroups

I am using a Red Hat 8.1 server.  I want to limit users using cgroups. I don't understand the order of operation when reading *.conf. I currently have the files :

```
[root@log01 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/cpu.conf
[Slice]
CPUQuota=80%
[root@log01 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/user-123.slice.d/cpu.conf
[Slice]
CPUQuota=50%
[root@log01 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/user-123.slice.d/memory.conf
[Slice]
MemoryMax=4G
[root@log01 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/user-0.slice.d/cpu.conf
[Slice]
CPUQuota=3200%
```

From my understanding of the documentation, `user-.slice.d` is set for all users.

I use `user-123.slice.d` and `user-0.slice.d` to override the setting from `user-.slice.d`.

**Question** :

1. What is the order of operation here?  Is `user-.slice.d` always read before the others?
2. What is the order of operation reading conf files in `user-123.slice.d`?  Does `cpu.conf` get read before or after `memory.conf`?  It seems like you can arbitrarily name your `*.conf` files.

Answer (score 1):

From the systemd unit man pages at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html, this part:

> Along with a unit file `foo.service`, a "drop-in" directory `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix ".conf" from this directory will be merged in the alphanumeric order and parsed after the main unit file itself has been parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files.
> Each drop-in file must contain appropriate section headers. For instantiated units, this logic will first look for the instance ".d/" subdirectory (e.g. "foo@bar.service.d/") and read its ".conf" files, followed by the template ".d/" subdirectory (e.g. "foo@.service.d/") and the ".conf" files there.
> Moreover for unit names containing dashes ("-"), the set of directories generated by repeatedly truncating the unit name after all dashes is searched too. Specifically, for a unit name `foo-bar-baz.service` not only the regular drop-in directory `foo-bar-baz.service.d/` is searched but also both `foo-bar-.service.d/` and `foo-.service.d/`. This is useful for defining common drop-ins for a set of related units, whose names begin with a common prefix. This scheme is particularly useful for mount, automount and slice units, whose systematic naming structure is built around dashes as component separators.
> Note that equally named drop-in files further down the prefix hierarchy override those further up, i.e. `foo-bar-.service.d/10-override.conf` overrides `foo-.service.d/10-override.conf`.

Comment: The only confusion that I have with this answer is that it isn't clear to me if the logic above applies for both user-.slice.d/ .  I'm not exactly sure the relationship between what the above logic for *-.service.d does for services and how it applies to the logic of what *-.slice.d do for users.

Answer (score 1):

According to my local Red Hat expert, it turns out that limiting groups of users are best limited by using `ulimit`.  `cgroups` are the tool to use to limit either individual processors or individual users.

According to my expert, my configuration above behaves as I want it to. The limits are set for all users by `user-slice.d/` and then (as suggested by Edward's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691747/128519)), the UIDs after the dash are then searched.

So the settings in `user-0.slice.d` does in fact override the settings set by `user-.slice.d` for ONLY the user with UID=0 (i.e. root).